# Promoting integers to 8 bytes including those with explicit declaration using IBM xlf compiler

Tags: compilation, compiler-flags, xl-fortran

When I use gfortran the flag -finteger-4-integer-8 does the job.

However, I'm looking for xlf's equivalent flag, -qintsize=8 is the equivalent of -fdefault-integer-8, but I haven't been able to find -finteger-4-integer-8's analog.

Comment: While XL Fortran does not currently have an equivalent option, if you explain what you're trying to achieve, we might be able to provide you with a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XL Fortran compiler does not have an equivalent option to gfortran's -finteger-4-integer-8 option.  (I'm an XL Fortran compiler developer.)